# Cannot find sqlite db file created with Entity Framework Core sqlite in winui3 project

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, winui-3

I have a WinUI 3 project where I initialized my `DbContext` like this:

```
public string DbPath; 

public MyAppContext()
{
    var folder = Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData;
    var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(folder);
    DbPath = System.IO.Path.Join(path, "MyApp.db");
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
=> options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbPath}");
```

I use `EnsureCreated()` in my `App.xaml.cs` to ensure the database is created.

I tried adding data (with code) and I checked that it is persisted, and everything works great so far.

Problem is: I want to be able to add data manually to the file while developing features but I can't find the file anywhere.

Using a breakpoint I checked the value of `DbPath` and I got

```
C:\Users\rahma\AppData\Local\MyApp.db
```

but there is nothing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is a packaged app and since, in general, packaged apps store their data in assigned folders, your "MyApp.db" should be stored in one of those folders, the [LocalCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localcachefolder?view=winrt-22621#windows-storage-applicationdata-localcachefolder) folder if I have to guess.

```cs
string localCacheFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.Path;
```

For your SQLite *.db file, I think you should check these [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases). They are for UWP apps but should also work for packaged WinUI 3 apps.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: I found my file in a weird location
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Packages\c99b3429-5803-478b-90b4-3e9fd1da8d42_kvaxvwfsem54g\LocalCache\Local